# ConcurrentModificationException while iterating through ArrayList

Tags: java

```
synchronized(queueClientList){
    Iterator<Client> iterator = queueClientList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        Client client = new Client();
        client = iterator.next();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(client.serviceTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        System.out.println(client.ID+ " it`s out");
        queueClientList.remove(client);
    }
}
```

This code should iterate through `queueClientList` and sleep the Thread for `client.serviceTime` milliseconds. After waking up, it should delete the current client from the `queueClientList`.

It gives me the `ConcurrentModificationException` at `client = iterator.next()` line

The declaration of queueClientList is:

```
public List<Client> queueClientList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Client>());
```

Why does it throw that error if this whole method is synchronized?

Comment: As an aside, this has nothing to do with threading/thread safety, as the concurrent modification all happens within the same thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
The problem was, that I was trying to remove from my list , while iterating thorugh it, which is impossible.